# React ref.current is undefined in useLayoutEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref, react-intersection-observer

I'm trying to implement a POC for a horizontally scrollable section on a project. I have 3 h3s next to each other above the horizontally scrollable section, the h3s should correspond to the individual sub-sections in the horizontal bit.

I am using react-intersection-observer to create refs to the sub-sections to be able to scroll to them when a user clicks on one of the h3s.
The state is being set correctly, and in React Dev Tools I can see that the useInView hooks are being set correctly and also show the s as refs. However, when I try to access refOne.current anywhere, it comes back undefined. I'm explicitly using useLayoutEffect here to wait for all DOM nodes to be fully painted, but still refOne.current is undefined.

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import classes from './Projects.module.css';
const Projects = () => {
    const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState('one');

    let [refOne, inViewOne, entryOne] = useInView({
        threshold: 1,
    });

    let [refTwo, inViewTwo, entryTwo] = useInView({
        threshold: 1,
    });

    let [refThree, inViewThree, entryThree] = useInView({
        threshold: 1,
    });

    useLayoutEffect(() => {

        console.log(refOne.current) // comes back undefined

        checkAndScroll(activeState);
    }, [activeState]);

    const setActiveHeading = (id) => {
        setActiveState(id);
    };

    let oneClasses = classNames(classes.heading, {
        [classes.activeHeading]: activeState === 'one',
    });
    let twoClasses = classNames(classes.heading, {
        [classes.activeHeading]: activeState === 'two',
    });
    let threeClasses = classNames(classes.heading, {
        [classes.activeHeading]: activeState === 'three',
    });

    const checkAndScroll = (id) => {

        console.log(refOne.current) // comes back undefined

        if (id === 'one' && !inViewOne) {
            scrollToRef(refOne);
        } else if (id === 'two' && !inViewTwo) {
            scrollToRef(refTwo);
        } else if (id === 'three' && !inViewThree) {
            scrollToRef(refThree);
        }
    };
    const scrollToRef = (ref) => {

        console.log(refOne.current) // comes back undefined

        if (ref && ref.current) {
            ref.current.scrollIntoView();
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.headingsContainer}>
                <h3
                    className={oneClasses}
                    id={classes.headingOne}
                    onClick={() => setActiveHeading('one')}
                >
                    One
                </h3>
                <h3
                    className={twoClasses}
                    id={classes.headingTwo}
                    onClick={() => setActiveHeading('two')}
                >
                    Two
                </h3>
                <h3
                    className={threeClasses}
                    id={classes.headingThree}
                    onClick={() => setActiveHeading('three')}
                >
                    Three
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div ref={refOne} className={classes.one} />
                <div ref={refTwo} className={classes.two} />
                <div ref={refThree} className={classes.three} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Projects;
```

I've been working on this for hours and I am at the end of my wits. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Little curious, have you tried `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect`?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, and it's hella stupid.

The react-intersection-observer hook provides a ref, an inView boolean, and an entry object. However, the **ref is not actually a ref.**

The **ref is a callback function** which does not contain a current property (hence the undefined). See the creator's comment here: https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer/issues/285#issuecomment-572980628

What you should do instead, is use the entry object it returns, and access the target property. If you have assigned your refs correctly, **entry.target** will contain the html node you assigned the ref to.

Answer (score 0):

### I'm explicitly using `useLayoutEffect` here to wait for all DOM nodes to be fully painted.

> Updates scheduled inside `useLayoutEffect` will be flushed synchronously, **before the browser has a chance to paint**.

React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) says this about `useLayoutEffect`.

Have you tried `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: Yes, I started with useEffect, but since it didn't work, I switched to useLayoutEffect. Anyway, I found the issue at hand and will post the correct response. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Cool. Naming convention in library `react-intersection-observer` is confusing/misleading then. Thanks for the answer BTW.